# Вызов разных функций при выборе разных значений в combobox

Tags: python, tkinter

Код:

```python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def callback1(event1):
     print("New")

def callback2(event2):
     print("New2")
     
GG = tk.Tk() 
GG.geometry('200x100')

arx1 = ttk.Combobox(GG,values=[1,2])


arx1.grid(column=0, row=0)
arx1.current(0)

arx1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackFunc)


GG.mainloop()
```

Вопрос:

Как сделать так, чтобы при выборе "1" выводило функцию `callback1`, а при выборе "2" функцию `callback2`?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: дайте вопросы более внятный заголовок.

Comment: @Эникейщик пойдёт?

Comment: @V-Mor вы, прочитав такой заголвок, поймете о чем спрашивается в вопросе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто сделайте общий колбэк, в нем проверяете какое значение выбрано, и вызываете нужный "дочерний" колбэк:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def callback1(event):
    print("New1")


def callback2(event):
    print("New2")


def callbackFunc(event):
    # Значения в комбо хранятся в строковом виде, поэтому сравнивать нужно со строкой
    if arx1.get() == "1":
        callback1(event)
    elif arx1.get() == "2":
        callback2(event)


GG = tk.Tk() 
GG.geometry('200x100')

arx1 = ttk.Combobox(GG,values=[1,2])

arx1.grid(column=0, row=0)
arx1.current(0)

arx1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", callbackFunc)


GG.mainloop()
```